# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to use maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

First of all, I'm using Android Studio and it's my first time using maps.

I created a project, with a Navigation Drawer Activity.

**File> New Project > Next > Next> Switched "Navigation Drawer Activity" and clicked next > Finish.**

After, I clicked in the project with the right button > **new > activity > google > google maps activity.**

I put google api maps key in google_maps_api.xml.

So I opened MainActivity, and type the following inside OnCreateView function:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    return rootView;
}
```

then I add after that the following two functions:

```
 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
   }    
private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
```

Everytime I try to execute it, I get a null pointer exception. Here is the complete error message:

```
04-14 19:44:40.204  4390-4390/ct.ufrn.br.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ct.ufrn.br.myapplication, PID: 4390
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ct.ufrn.br.myapplication/ct.ufrn.br.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ct.ufrn.br.myapplication.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:142)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1194)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5258)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Do you know how to solve it?

obs: I tryied the same with a blank activity (in onCreate method, instead onCreateView), and it worked well.

Here is the activity_maps.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context="ct.ufrn.br.myapplication.MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: can you please post your XML layout file?

Comment: In the future, please put the stack trace in the question directly. "So I opened MainActivity, and type the following inside OnCreateView function" -- there is no `onCreateView()` for an `Activity`. There is a for a fragment, and your Java stack trace shows that you are crashing in an `onCreateView()` of a `PlaceholderFragment`. However, your stack trace did not come from the code in your question, as there is no statement in that question that can *directly* trigger a `NullPointerException`. Please ensure that your stack trace comes from the code that you put in your question.

Comment: CommonsWare, I'm sure that stack trace came from the code above. I may send the complete project to you, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I solved replacing

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

with

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```